# Access data passed from an url in a view Django Rest Api

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working with a DRF. I am building a custom function that counts the number of posts of a user hence I not using a class based view.

I am not able to access the userid I pass into the url in the view. I have tried the following

Urls.py

```
url(r'^count/(?P<userid>[0-9]+)/$', views.Count),
```

Views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
def Count(self):
   userid = self.kwargs['userid']
```

I get the following error:

Count() got an unexpected keyword argument 'userid'

This approach works fine for class based views... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your "hence" does not follow; there's no reason not to do that in a class-based view. But since you have decided not to use a class, why are you using class concepts like `self`?

Comment: If the answer helped you please accept it to prevent others from posting here. Its a good practice in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this: `def Count(request):` to this `def Count(request, userid):`

You see your `Count` view expects a `userid` parameter to be passed (via your urk), which in your case is missing. Simply, add it and you are good to go!

Then inside your `Count` you no longer have to do `userid = self.kwargs['userid']`. Just use it from the parameter passed!